# Change Dialogs Buttons Color Nativescript angular android

Tags: android, angular, dialog, nativescript

[image]

I am using nativescript Dialog confirm function, it works in IOS but in android,
I have a problem like an image above sometimes it will show with black text on the button but mostly it is just like the image.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to change the [color](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3198#issuecomment-263568730) and the [background-color](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3220) of Dialog through the `Button` CSS properties.

There are some limitations for the dialogs module discussed in this [thread](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3830). You can use [**modal** pages](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#modal-pages) instead

Comment: I already know about the links above, unfortunately, links could not help this situation. But I found another solution and could change the dialog color